# iOS-charts slow down my app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-charts

I'm using `ios-chart` to present a calendar I've built. I'm currently using `LineChart` to plot my data, and I plot 1 point for each day of the year in one chart. So I have 365 points plotted in one chart. And it takes like 1 second to draw it. This isn't a huge issue, except that I have my calendar as a `TableViewCell`, which will result in a very hacky scroll once the `TableViewCell` is scrolled outside the `ContentView` and then scrolled back again (so the cell gets redrawn). It feels weird that it takes so long to draw around 400 points, even on an iPhone 6. I might be doing something wrong here?

My setup code for the chart:

```
lineChart.descriptionText = ""
        lineChart.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
        lineChart.userInteractionEnabled = false
        lineChart.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        lineChart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        lineChart.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
        lineChart.drawBordersEnabled = false
        lineChart.leftAxis.enabled = false
        lineChart.rightAxis.enabled = false
        lineChart.legend.enabled = false
        lineChart.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill

        var xVals = [String]()
        var dataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: [ChartDataEntry]())
        for (index, value) in enumerate(plotData){
            dataSet.addEntry(ChartDataEntry(value: Float(value), xIndex: index))
            xVals.append("\(index)")
        }

        dataSet.setColor(Colors.whiteColor())
        dataSet.lineWidth = 1.0
        dataSet.circleRadius = 0.0
        dataSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
        dataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
        dataSet.fillColor = Colors.whiteColor()
        dataSet.fillAlpha = 0.1
        dataSet.valueTextColor = Colors.whiteColor()

        lineChart.data = LineChartData(xVals: xVals, dataSet: dataSet)
```

The code above is done each time a cell is created (or reused). Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the [Time Profile](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/TimeProfilerInstrument/TimeProfilerInstrument.html) in [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

Comment: @Mats never used that before. Thanks, found the bottleneck :)! Had nothing to do with ios-charts.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in data that was being setup each time I reused the cell. Data creation should obviously not be in a cell, but somewhere else. Should be solved once I move my data initiation somewhere else.

Comment: obviously true according to MVC